# Net Use and ForEach with Variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am performing a slightly unusual task in that i'm running a PowerShell script which performs various tasks. One step of the task requires me to map network drives using `NET USE` (on old XP devices). I have a list of Device, IP in a CSV but, am struggling to pull out the Device Name from the CSV when using Foreach as, i'm embedding the variable from the `ForEach` loop in the path of the net use command and, PowerShell is not interpreting it how i would expect.

```
CSV: Column 1 = Device, Column 2 = IP
```

Code:

```
$Site = "ABC"
$mapdevs = Import-Csv "C:\DEVS\$Site.csv"
          ForEach ($dev in $mapdevs) {
          & Net Use * \\$dev.Device\c$ /user:admin P@ssw0rd }
```

Does anyone know how i can retrive the column value from the CSV and embed in the net use line?

Otherwise i thought this might work:

```
$Site = "ABC"
$mapdevs = Import-Csv "C:\DEVS\$Site.csv"
          ForEach ($dev.Device in $mapdevs) {
          & Net Use * \\$dev.Device\c$ /user:admin P@ssw0rd }
```

Definitely not right as a second attempt. I can't use New-PSDrive because, the end point systems don't support WMF.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When expanding a `$Variable.Property` in a string you have to use an enclosing `$()`
to force evaluation otherwise only `$Variable` is expanded and `.Property` treated as text.
You might need to escape literal `$` with a backtick.

So use

```
& Net Use * ("\\$($dev.Device)\c`$") /user:admin P@ssw0rd
```

Alternativly use the `-f` format operator

```
& Net Use * ("\\{0}\c`$" -f $dev.Device) /user:admin P@ssw0rd
```

Concatenating also should work:

```
& Net Use * ("\\"+$dev.Device+"\c`$") /user:admin P@ssw0rd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach ($dev in $devs) {
              & Net Use * "\\" + $dev.Device + "\c$" /user:admin P@ssw0rd }
```

The above seems to concatenate the string using the variable and select the right info, much closer but still not completely right

Comment: what is not right? does the following return the correct unc path you expect? `foreach ($dev in $devs) { '\\', $dev.Device, '\c$' -join ''}`

Comment: That does not encapsulate the /user:admin P@ss unfortunately - looking into it

Comment: What is the double apostrophe for?

Comment: http://jon.netdork.net/2015/09/08/powershell-and-single-vs-double-quotes/